# Combine Same Item Number into one cell Like concatinate function

Tags: excel

Hy Experts, I have an excel sheet with four columns. Column 1 is Part_No, Column 2 is Type, Column 3 is Col2 as Year and column 4 is Item Name.

Actually the column 1 as C column contains many Part_No with same number like 08256 is in sheet 2 times as row one and two. But in some cases the rows are very far from the same number. I used simple this function.

```
=concatenate(E,F)
```

It can combine only one row but I want to combine all the rows in one cell that have same Part_No. How it could be. Thanks

The structure of excel is as under.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong with what you are currently doing? Sorry, the issue isn't immediately evident

Comment: @urdearboy bro plz check the image

Comment: Maybe i'm alone in not seeing the issue right away, but you should probably give the people *who are donating their time to your problem* the benefit of the doubt. I viewed the image and was looking for clarification. - **urdearBro**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($C$2:$C$100 = C2,$E$2:$E$100 & " " & $F$2:$F$100,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel